# Java-How to Print names along with sorted dates?

Tags: java, regex, date-sorting

I have a file with names and DateOfbirths. I am matching the BateOfBirths with the regex and i want to store them into an array so that i can sort dates. What i have done is
Text file:

```
name1   dd-MM-yyyy  
name2   dd-MM-yyyy
namw3  dd-MM-yyyy
name4  dd-MM-yyyy
```

my code:

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

class SortDate{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dates.txt"));
File file = new File("dates.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
int count = 0;
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
String line = scanner.nextLine();
count++;
}
String[] names= new String[count];
List<Date> birthDates = new ArrayList<Date>();

for(int x=0;x<count;x++)
{
names[x]=br.readLine();
}
String Dates="\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d\\d";
Pattern pat=Pattern.compile(Dates);
for(String s:names){
try {

Matcher mat=pat.matcher(s);
while(mat.find()){
String str=mat.group();
DateFormat formatter ;

Date date ;
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
date = (Date)formatter.parse(str);  
birthDates.add(date);

}
}catch (ParseException e)
  {System.out.println("Exception :"+e);  } }
  Collections.sort(birthDates);

System.out.println(names+birthDates);
}}
```

I am able to print the sorted dates but how can i print the names along with the dates. thanks

Comment: Declare `String[] dobs=new String[names.length];` now you can store into it using an index. And at the end if you want a date array, create a `Date[]` of the same length as the `dobs` and use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the string to date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create an `ArrayList` and store them in there.

```
List<String> birthDates = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern datePattern = Pattern.compile("\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d\\d");
for(String name : names) {
    Matcher m = datePattern.matcher(name);
    while(m.find()) {
        birthDates.add(m.group());
    }
}
```

One thing to keep in mind is that you plan on sorting these. You can probably get away with using the String comparator and using `Collections.sort(birthDates)`. In the case that you need a `Date` object, you can use `m.group()` and parse it into a `Date` object. Then, simply change your `ArrayList` type to be `ArrayList<Date>`.

Edit: If you *really* need it to be an array, you can then use the `.toArray(T[])` in the `List` interface to change it.

```
String[] birthDatesArray = birthDates.toArray(new String[birthDates.size()]);
```

Comment: @lan How can i parse m.group to Date ?

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");` and then `birthDates.add(sdf.parse(m.group()));`

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
while (mat.find()) {
    System.out.println(mat.group());
}
```

**Edited**

I'm sorry I didn't notice your question. To save results:

```
import java.util.*;

...

List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while (mat.find()) {
    matches.add(mat.group());
}
```

Comment: I edited the que. I want to save the mat.group() to an array. thanks.