# Java-Can we keep Regex match as Hash value?

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have a text file with names and Date Of Births, I need to sort by dates,  Like

```
Fname LastName  dd-MM-yyyy
Fname2 Lname2  dd-MM-yyyy
Fname3 Lname3      dd-MM-yyyy
Fname4   Lname4    dd-MM-yyyy
Fname5 Lname5 dd-MM-yyyy
```

Can i take the DOB as hash values by matching with RegEx like `"\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d\\d"` and Names as Hashkey, So that Sorting by DOF would be easy. Or suggest me how to split that to Column[0] Column[1] so that Column[1] has Dates.

Comment: Have you considered creating a DateOfBirth object with the name and date to represent your entries? You could easily order them by implementing Comparable ou creating a Comparator.

Comment: I did something like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578591/java-how-to-print-names-along-with-sorted-dates/9578665#comment12151779_9578665)

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is that determining how to split the name will not be easy.  Some last names have spaces, some first names have spaces:

```
Jill St. John
Billy Bob Thornton
```

I'd recommend adding a delimiter to make solving this easier.

Then, encapsulate the name and DOB fields in a class called "Person", for example.

Add your persons to a List.  Then you can implement [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) to sort your list.

The problem with using a hash value is that duplicates are not allowed in the garden-variery HashMap and TreeMap classes.  That is, if two people have birthdays on the same date, one will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract these data from the file anyway. So I would suggest creating class for the data and implement a comparable interface:

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

    static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_PARSER = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    Date dateOfBirth;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String dateOfBirth) throws     ParseException {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.dateOfBirth = DATE_PARSER.parse(dateOfBirth);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        return this.dateOfBirth.compareTo(o.dateOfBirth);
    }
}
```

Now, during the reading just put all those records into [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) implementation, for example: [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html). You can also store records into an array or List and sort them using [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) or [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class. The most important is part is implementing Comparable.

Comment: Will SortedSet allow duplicate DOBs?

Comment: The sort answer is no. In general, Sets do not allow duplicates. If you need to have duplicates - use List implementation (for example ArrayList) and sort it using Collections.sort(personList).